# Understanding registers from a layman's view

Tags: c

I have been watching various tutorials on youtube on the topic of how computers work and i can't say i know how data is stored in memory yet.

To begin with,i am looking at 32 bit systems and on this wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit and i quote

> A 32-bit register can store 2<sup>32</sup> different values. The signed range of
>   integer values that can be stored in 32 bits is -2,147,483,648 through
>   2,147,483,647 (unsigned: 0 through 4,294,967,295). Hence, a processor
>   with 32-bit memory addresses can directly access 4 GiB of
>   byte-addressable memory.

In my understanding,memory locations are from 0 to 4,294,967,295 so i can store information in any of those locations but the -2,147,483,648 totally confuses me or its possible i am understanding everything wrong.

Can someone please clarify what the quoted text really means in an easy to understand way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph is talking about the number of possible distinct values that can be represented in a 32-bit register. There are 2<sup>32</sup> of them, because each bit can have two values and there are 32 bits. Depending on the circumstances, these 2<sup>32</sup> distinct representations are used for 4,294,967,295 positive values, or for 2,147,483,648 negative and 2,147,483,647 positive ones. A clever representation of negative numbers ([two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)) and flags mean that the instructions for signed and unsigned interpretations of the values of the registers can be the same.

This has nothing to do with the number of registers available in the processor, which is typically between 8 and 100 depending how you count them.

Comment: @user3272483 “a 32-bit” does not have any memory locations. A **32-bit address space** represents 4,294,967,296 addresses (typically, of bytes), but you cannot use all these addresses for various reasons (some languages reserve 0 for NULL, the Operating System's kernel can reserve as much as half the addresses, libraries use some addresses that aren't available for your own code or data, you may not have that much physical+swap memory on your computer, …)

Answer (score 1):

The quote describes 2 different ways the register values can be interpreted: unsigned values and signed values. When signed, bit 31 is used to indicate a negative number which is then coded in "two's complement" format. Memory addresses are referenced by unsigned values. *Offsets* from a specific memory address can be (but are not always) represented by signed values.

Whether the range is -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647 or 0 through 4,294,967,295 there are still 4,294,967,296 distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU registers are not only for memory addressing. In particular they are used in basic arithmetic operations like addition or multiplication. How they are interpreted (i.e. signed/unsigned) depends on assembly instruction (by ISA), that are subject to.

The memory addressing is likely to work with unsigned representation, however this may be not always true, at least not as simple as that.